# How to make Flutter app show up in 'Default digital assistant apps' on Android device?

Tags: flutter

Wondering how one makes an app show up as a Digital assistant app with Flutter.

I want the app to be listed here:

[image]

Does anyone know? I have searched all over but have not found the answer.

Searched online a lot.

Expecting to find some configurations or something to add so this would be possible.